# Not able to make the ajax request with my header given by ember-simple-auth authorizers

Tags: ajax, ember.js, ember-cli, ember-simple-auth

I have developed a template (feedheader.hbs) which I am rendering in my feed template like {{ render 'feedheader' feedheader}}.This feedheader contains the username and profile pic of user.I need to send the the requests  to http://example.com/api/users/profile/?targetuser=-1 along with my auth header to get the user details.So I made a controller for feedheader and made the ajax requests.I am using ember-simple-auth (fb login ) for authorization.

controller.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import OAuth2Bearer from 'ember-simple-auth/authorizers/oauth2-bearer';

const { service } = Ember.inject;

export default Ember.Controller.extend(OAuth2Bearer,{
      session:service('session'),
      init:function(){
            this.get('session').authorize('authorizer:application', (headerName, headerValue) => {
              const headers = {};
              headers[headerName] = headerValue;
              Ember.$.ajax('http://example.com/api/users/profile/?targetuser=-1', { headers });
});

      }


});
```

But it throws an error in console

```
 "Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Expected hash or Mixin instance, got [object Function]"
```

authorizers(application.js)

```
import OAuth2Bearer from 'ember-simple-auth/authorizers/oauth2-bearer';

export default OAuth2Bearer.extend();
```

The authorizers is working fine in my adapter.There is some simple thing I am missing and not able to fix this.Please tell how to send the ajax request with my authorizers header.

Comment: please read simple auth documentation

Answer (score -1):

The way you're sending the headers doesn't look right to me. Instead of

```
Ember.$.ajax('http://example.com/api/users/profile/?targetuser=-1', { headers });
```

it should be

```
Ember.$.ajax('http://example.com/api/users/profile/?targetuser=-1', { headers: headers });
```

Comment: What ES6 feature is that?? @Bek

Comment: you don't need key if `key` and `variable name` match when you pass to object (http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2013/02/es6-and-object-literal-property-value-shorthand.html)

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about that one!